# Ansible - list which hosts are rescued

Tags: ansible

One can recover failed hosts using `rescue`. How can I configure Ansible so that the other hosts in the play are aware of the host which will be recovered?

I thought I was smart, and tried using difference between `ansible_play_hosts_all` and `ansible_play_batch`, but Ansible doesn't list the failed host, since it's rescued.

```yaml
---
- hosts:
    - host1
    - host2
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - block:
        - name: fail one host
          shell: /bin/false
          when: inventory_hostname == 'host1'
  
        # returns an empty list
        - name: list failed hosts
          debug:
            msg: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all | difference(ansible_play_batch) }}"
          
      rescue:
        - shell: /bin/true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "*How can I configure Ansible so that the other hosts in the play are aware of the host which will be recovered?*"

It seems that according documentation [Handling errors with blocks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html#handling-errors-with-blocks)

> *If any tasks in the block return failed, the rescue section executes tasks to recover from the error. ... Ansible provides a couple of variables for tasks in the `rescue` portion of a block: `ansible_failed_task`, `ansible_failed_result`*

as well the source of [`ansible/playbook/block.py`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/playbook/block.py), such functionality isn't implemented yet.

You may need to implement some logic to keep track of the content of return values of `ansible_failed_task` and on which host it happened during execution. Maybe it is possible to use [`add_host` module – Add a host (and alternatively a group) to the ansible-playbook in-memory inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/add_host_module.html) with parameter `groups: has_rescued_tasks`.

Or probably do further investigation beginning with default [Callback plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback.html) and Ansible Issue #[48418](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/48418) "*Add stats on rescued/ignored tasks*" since it added statistics about rescued tasks.

Comment: Yes, I thought perhaps there was a more elegant way of solving this issue at hand. But your answer is just the way it is, thanks!